# Error for my model with ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, openweathermap

I am working for a personal project that is using an API and having user authentication with JWT (but used in serializer). I wanted to implement `ManyToManyField` for `user` and `city` but it doesn't work properly. [This is the extended model I have found](https://my.vertabelo.com/model/0PkxLvfBKVHKaAbi8u2dbReV53zsoWWs) and [django aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/) . I want that the  `UserSearchLocation` to store the `City` and when logged in to see the city, while other users will not see it until the search same city.

models.py

```
class UserSearchLocation(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=85, blank=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name


class City(models.Model):
    user_searched_locations = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
                                  through='UsersLocations',
                                  through_fields=('city', 'user'),
                                  related_name="my_cities",
                                  blank=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=85)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=85, blank=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4,
                                   null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4,
                                    null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    #users_location = models.ManyToManyField(UserSearchLocation)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.location}, {self.country_code}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.location = self.location.capitalize()
        self.country = self.country.capitalize()
        self.country_code = self.country_code.capitalize()
        return super(City, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'
        unique_together = ("location", "country_code")


class UsersLocations(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='locations_by_users',
                             null=True)
```

To add in `localhost/admin/` a `City` works, but when to add a `UserSearchLocation` I have this error:

```
Exception Value:    
column base_usersearchlocation.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "base_usersearchlocation"."user_id", "base_usersearch...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says the `city.location` doesn't exist - location is a `CharField` on your City model - are you sure you've run migrations and don't have any naming conflicts?

Comment: I have updated the model now as above. I deleted all migrations and done again `makemigrations` and `migrate`. I can add a City which is not assigned to anyone, but for `UserSearchLocation` throw me the error when I assign `user` and `city` to a `name`